# colmap localization: get camera position

Tags: computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction, structure-from-motion

I'm using [colmap](https://colmap.github.io/index.html#). I succeed to visualize a 3D sparse reconstitution from a video.

Now I have some new images from the same scene and I want to (only) localize them. I want the (x,y,z, angles) of the camera.

Following [the doc](https://colmap.github.io/faq.html#register-localize-new-images-into-an-existing-reconstruction), I used the commands `colmap feature_extractor` and `colmap vocab_tree_matcher`.

Everything seemed to get well; the output is

```
Indexing image [1/23] in 0,022s
...
Indexing image [23/23] in 0,077s
Matching image [1/16] in 0,078s
...
Matching image [16/16] in 0,003s
Elapsed time: 0,043 [minutes]
```

But now what ?
How do I query the colmap database to get the (x,y,z,angle) of image, say, 12 ?

I want to programmatically get the information.